# Joining multiple lists coming in function output python

Tags: python, list

I am getting multiple lists as an output to a function. I want to combine all the lists and form only one list. Please help

```
def words(*args):
    word =[args]
    tokens = nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(''.join(word))
    for word in tokens:
        final = wn.synsets(word)
        synonyms = set()
        for synset in final:
            for synwords in synset.lemma_names:
                synonyms.add(synwords)
        final = list(synonyms)
        dic = dict(zip(word,final))
        dic[word] = final
        return final
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)

Comment: The way you have written your code, after the first word in the tokens is processed, your function will return; because `return final` is in the body of the `for` loop. Are you sure this is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Use this wherever you are using words function (which is a list of lists according to your question):

`wordlist = [word for sublist in words(args) for word in sublist]`

Answer (score 0):

Once your code is corrected I find no problem with function `words()` returning anything other than a flat list. If there is some input that reproduces the problem please update your question with it.

The correction is to pass `args` directly into `join()`, not to wrap it in a list.

```
def words(*args):
    tokens = nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(''.join(args))
    for word in tokens:
        final = wn.synsets(word)
        synonyms = set()
        for synset in final:
            for synwords in synset.lemma_names:
                synonyms.add(synwords)
        final = list(synonyms)
        dic = dict(zip(word,final))
        dic[word] = final
        return final

>>> words('good day', ', this is a', ' test!', 'the end.')
['beneficial', 'right', 'secure', 'just', 'unspoilt', 'respectable', 'good', 'goodness', 'dear', 'salutary', 'ripe', 'expert', 'skillful', 'in_force', 'proficient', 'unspoiled', 'dependable', 'soundly', 'honorable', 'full', 'undecomposed', 'safe', 'adept', 'upright', 'trade_good', 'sound', 'in_effect', 'practiced', 'effective', 'commodity', 'estimable', 'well', 'honest', 'near', 'skilful', 'thoroughly', 'serious']
```